# Passcode reset without factory resetting phone

Tags: locked-out

My girls put a passcode on my phone. If I try and guess 1 more time it will factory reset. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Christina! Our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) should get you started. You're not the first one with that issue, so we collected some first-aid there.

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot is to use the `Android Device Manager` to force a temporary password. Go ahead and Google it. It should be the first result. This is the Google equivalent of find my iPhone.

Once this is open, sign in using the Google account that's associated with the phone. You should be able to locate the phone, but what you want is the lock function. Set a different password you know with a message. When the phone displays that message, it's safe to unlock the phone using the temporary password you just set. From here you can go into the phone's settings and disable the password.